# 1 Button triggering random sounds (from an array?) in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, button, audio

I've figured out how to trigger a sound when the button is pressed. I'm stuck on triggering a random sound when that same button is pressed. Since the audio player will take a string, I've generated a random number, but don't know how to insert that random number in the player. The code below is really broken so please bear with me there, I'm just stuck.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mainButton: UIButton!

var sound1: AVAudioPlayer?
var sound2: AVAudioPlayer?
var sound3: AVAudioPlayer?
var sound4: AVAudioPlayer?

//There are many more sounds, but this is short for the example

var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

func setupAudioPlayerWithFile(file: NSString, type: NSString) -> AVAudioPlayer? {

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as String, ofType: type as String)
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)

    var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer?

    do {
        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
    } catch {
        print("Player not available")
    }
    return audioPlayer
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let sound1 = self.setupAudioPlayerWithFile("sound1", type: "aif")
    {self.sound1 = sound1}

    if let sound2 = self.setupAudioPlayerWithFile("sound2", type: "aif")
    {self.sound2 = sound2}

    if let sound3 = self.setupAudioPlayerWithFile("sound3", type: "aif")
    {self.sound3 = sound3}

    if let sound4 = self.setupAudioPlayerWithFile("sound4", type: "aif")
    {self.sound4 = sound4}

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject){
    let audioArray: NSArray = ["1, 2, 3, 4"] 
    let range: UInt32 = UInt32(audioArray.count)
    number = Int(arc4random_uniform(range))

    sound(number)?.play()
}
}
```

Comment: Put 4 strings into one array, generate a random number from 1-4, then use it to setup your audio player

Comment: The "setup audio player" part is where I'm not sure how to do

Comment: Read the Apple document for that class then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mainButton: UIButton!

// PUT SOUNDS AS STRINGS IN ARRAY
var arrayOfSounds = ["sound1", "sound2", "sound3", "sound4"]



var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

func setupAudioPlayerWithFile(file: NSString, type: NSString) -> AVAudioPlayer? {

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as String, ofType: type as String)
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)

    var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer?

    do {
        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
    } catch {
        print("Player not available")
    }
    return audioPlayer
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject){
    let range: UInt32 = UInt32(arrayOfSounds.count)
    number = Int(arc4random_uniform(range))
    //FIND OUT WHICH SOUND HERE
    let sound = self.setupAudioPlayerWithFile(arrayOfSounds[number], type: "aif")
    sound.play()
}
}
```

Comment: By the way, this line `sound(number)?.play()` was the main problem. You can't create a variable or object name by splicing together other objects. Instead, `sound()` calls a function that doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you so much. This "let sound = self.setupAudioPlayerWithFile(arrayOfSounds[number], type: "aif")" was exactly what I was looking for. Mucho appreciation!